# Generators of vector space $R^3$

Tags: vector-spaces

I have a vector space $V$ ($R^3$) and choose one vector $v ∈ V$ such that there is no zero in that vector. Now I want to find a set of generators $G$ that generates $V$ such that coeficients of linear dependency are

1. unambiguous
2. ambiguous
3. nonexistent

I believe I know how to find 1. and 2., but I am puzzled with 3. I think  that it is not possible to have a set of vectors that generate $V$ and then have a $v ∈ V$ such that it cannot be expressed as linear combination of these generators, because it would mean that they are not actually generating whole vector space $R^3$ but only subspace. Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, then you are right:

You have some set $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ of generators of $V$. Since they generate $V$, any $v\in V$ can be written as a linear combination of this set of generators, so

$$v = a_1v_1+\ldots+a_nv_n,$$

for some scalars $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$. Indeed, by definition of a set of generators, the "coefficients of linear dependency" will always exist.